# How to add environment variables using module "lambda_function" - Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using aws version 3.50.0, but with for_each to read from _variables.tf. My main.tf is given below. When I comment out *environment* section as shown below, everything works. But how to add *environment* variables? When I uncomment and run the plan it throws this error:

```
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│ 
│   on main.tf line 22, in module "lambda_function":
│   22:   environment {
│ 
│ Blocks of type "environment" are not expected here.
│
│ make: *** [Makefile:44: plan] Error 1
______________________________________________________


locals {
  functions = {
    for function in local.workspace:
    function.name => function
  }
}

module "lambda_function" {

  source = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"

  for_each = local.functions

  function_name                  = "${element(split("-", terraform.workspace), 4)}-${each.value.name}"
  description                    = lookup(each.value, "description", "Not applicable")
  handler                        = "${each.value.name}.lambda_handler"
  memory_size                    = 128
  reserved_concurrent_executions = lookup(each.value, "reserved_concurrent_executions", 5)
  source_path = "${each.value.name}.py"
  runtime                        = "python3.8"
  
  # environment {
  #     variables = {
  #       LOTJM_ENV = "${element(split("-", terraform.workspace), 4)}"
  #     }
  # }
  
  tags = {
    Name = "${element(split("-", terraform.workspace), 4)}-${each.value.name}"
  }
}
```

Comment: By reading the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws/latest?tab=inputs) and using a `environment_variables` variable / parameter instead, not a block and not an arbitrarily named one.

Comment: If you look at the documentation of the module it says to use: `environment_variables`. That should fix the issue for you. I also have a terraform module for lambda that you can use if you need help: https://github.com/tomarv2/terraform-aws-lambda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation for this module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws/latest?tab=inputs), there's an optional input variable called `environment_variables` which is documented as follows:

> *environment_variables* `map(string)`
>
> Description: A map that defines environment variables for the Lambda Function.
>
> Default: `{}`

This suggests that the intended way to set environment variables for this module would be something like the following:

```
module "lambda_function" {
  source   = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"
  for_each = local.functions

  # ...

  environment_variables = {
    LOTJM_ENV = element(split("-", terraform.workspace), 4)
  }
}
```

This is a similar approach as for setting the `tags` variable, which is also declared as expecting a `map(string)` value.